# Computing Percentages in SPARQL

Tags: aggregate, sparql, linked-data

I have an ontology (called CODO) about patients of the Covid pandemic. One of our classes is a Cluster and each patient codo:isMemberOf one and only one Cluster. I want to compute the percentage of patients in each Cluster using SPARQL. Also, we have the inverse property as well codo:hasMember linking a Cluster to a Patient if that is easier to compute.

Comment: Try something like this:
`SELECT ?cluster (?x/?n AS ?proportion)
WHERE{
{SELECT ?cluster (COUNT(?patient) AS ?x)
WHERE{ 
?patient codo:isMemberOf ?cluster}
GROUP BY ?cluster}
{SELECT (COUNT(?patient) AS ?n)
WHERE{ 
?patient codo:isMemberOf ?cluster}}
}`

Comment: The first subquery will compute how many patients of a specific cluster. The second will compute how many patients are members of *any* cluster.
Then the outer query will divide the two numbers and tell you the proportion for each cluster.

Comment: you'll have to cast one of the count values to a double, otherwise the result will always be 0: `SELECT ?cluster (xsd:double(?x)/?n AS ?proportion) `

Comment: @Valerio_Cocchi  Thanks. I'm new to this site. I want to accept one answer and mark the others as helpful but I don't see how to do that. The help says there should be a "greyed out" check box next to the answer that I can click to accept the answer but all I see is a greyed out flag to the left of each answer which to flag it as inappropriate.

Comment: @MichaelDeBellis: Welcome to the site! The reason you cannot accept an answer is that there are no answers on this question, only comments.

Comment: @KonradHöffner  Thanks very much for the explanation.

Comment: I wish people would stop posting their answers as comments. It’s false modesty that makes it impossible, among other things, to rely on the answer counts in search results.